# How to perform fast search on JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file that contains many objects and options.

Each of these kinds:

```
{"item": "name", "itemId": 78, "data": "Some data", ..., "option": number or string}
```

There are about 10,000 objects in the file.

And when part of item value("ame", "nam", "na", etc) entered , it should display all the objects and their options that match this part.

RegExp is the only thing that comes to my mind, but at 200mb+ file it starts searching for a long time(2 seconds+)

That's how I'm getting the object right now:

```
let reg = new RegExp(enteredName, 'gi'), //enteredName for example "nam"
    data = await fetch("myFile.json"),
    jsonData = await data.json();

let results = jsonData.filter(jsonObj => {
    let item = jsonObj.item,
        itemId = String(jsonObj.itemId);
    return reg.test(item) || reg.test(itemId);
});
```

But that option is too slow for me.

What method is faster to perform such search using js?

Comment: Is this a one-time search, or do you need to search several times on the same JSON file?

Comment: Many times on the same file ( it can also be cached)

Comment: Then you need to put it into a dictionary, hashtable or similar data structure that has `O(1)` or `O(n log n)` time complexity.

Comment: Like using JSON.parse?

Comment: Using `includes` (or even `indexOf`) may be faster than regex but you'll have to `toLowerCase()` both first to keep it case-insensitive.

Comment: Plus a `for` loop is faster then `.filter` method. Not much faster but still, it can save you some time on 200+mb file.

Comment: Your question doesn't really have anything to do with JSON.  You've only parsed the JSON once... that's a good thing.  Beyond that, you're dealing with regular JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 0):

Looking up items by item number should be easy enough by creating a hash table, which others have already suggested. The big problem here is searching for items by name. You could burn a ton of RAM by creating a tree, but I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you're not necessarily looking for raw lookup speed. Instead, I'm assuming that you just want something that'll update a list on-the-fly as you type, without actually interrupting your typing, is that correct?

To that end, what you need is a search function that won't lock-up the main thread, allowing the DOM to be updated between returned results. Interval timers are one way to tackle this, as they can be set up to iterate through large, time-consuming volumes of data while allowing for other functions (such as DOM updates) to be executed between each iteration.

I've created a Fiddle that does just that:

```
// Create a big array containing items with names generated randomly for testing purposes
let jsonData = [];

for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  var itemName = '';
  jsonData.push({ item: Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) });
}

// Now on to the actual search part

let returnLimit = 1000; // Maximum number of results to return
let intervalItr = null; // A handle used for iterating through the array with an interval timer

function nameInput (e) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '';
  if (intervalItr) clearInterval(intervalItr); // If we were iterating through a previous search, stop it.
  if (e.value.length > 0) search(e.value);
}

let reg, idx

function search (enteredName) {
  reg = new RegExp(enteredName, 'i');
  idx = 0;

  // Kick off the search by creating an interval that'll call searchNext() with a 0ms delay.
  // This will prevent the search function from locking the main thread while it's working,
  // allowing the DOM to be updated as you type
  intervalItr = setInterval(searchNext, 0);
}

function searchNext() {
  if (idx >= jsonData.length || idx > returnLimit) {
    clearInterval(intervalItr);
    return;
  }
  let item = jsonData[idx].item;
  if (reg.test(item)) document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += '<br>' + item;
  idx++;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/FlimFlamboyant/we4r36tp/26/

Note that this could also be handled with a WebWorker, but I'm not sure it's strictly necessary.

Additionally, this could be further optimized by utilizing a secondary array that is filled as the search takes place. When you enter an additional character and a new search is started, the new search could begin with this secondary array, switching to the original if it runs out of data.